# Google Chrome App filesystem events, shell/finder integration

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome-app

For a new desktop app project I'm researching if it's feasible to create a cross-platform implementation instead of native Windows and OS X apps. [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) seemed promising, but after browsing through the Chrome APIs there are some things I didn't see that I'll need in my app:

- Notifications on changes to files in the local filesystem. (File System Events API on OS X, FileSystemWatcher on Windows.) At first I thought the syncFileSystem API might help with this, but it's apparently only for syncing with Google Drive, which is not what I need. I guess I could workaround this by scanning the directories I'm watching on a timer, but that won't perform well if there are a lot of directories and/or files.
- Ability to add context menus in Windows shell and OS X Finder, as I would be able to with a Windows shell extension or OS X Finder plugin.
- Ideally (although probably not a hard requirement) get the app into the Windows System Tray / OS X Menu Bar (NSStatusItem).

Can anyone confirm whether it's possible to access this functionality with a Chrome App? If not, can you recommend an alternative cross-platform tool for building an app with these features?

Comment: I think the first bullet point could make it into chrome.fileSystem API if you shared your use case on crbug. I believe google already has a private API that allows them to do this (Files app in ChromeOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the listed features have bugs logged, but no real progress at the moment:

Watch: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148873

File manager integration: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130455

Sys tray: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142450

The first of these to be made available will probably be file manager integration, which is being worked on now.

We'd love to improve watching but it is a significant task to support this on all operating systems and we don't have anyone working on it now.

Sys tray support is something we have no plans to release soon as we're not sure how we want to support this on ChromeOS.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks like Chrome Apps won't work for this project but I'll consider it for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything close to the items you have mentioned. I did however find this product: [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) that likely would get you onto both your target platforms, use the same basic code-base (HTML5/CSS/JS) and allow some possible per-OS customization. There is even a 'watch' project under NPM that covers your first bullet point. Check node-webkit/wiki for notes on how to add C/C++ extensions to their node build (under using-node-modules.) Project seems active and appears to be backed by Intel (they re-built their XDK product on it to do cross platform.)

Comment: Hi James! The fact that the Chrome API includes support for synchronizing files with Google Drive, but apparently does not provide generic support that would allow one to build sync to say, DropBox, for example, suggests that not only are there security concerns, but also proprietary concerns in keeping developers tied to the Google ecosystem. I'm investigating Mono as another alternative.

Comment: As the writer of the document linked to, I take exception to the assertion about not trusting our developers. We did provide directory read (and write). The document was intended to outline all the objections that had been raised, up to that point, to not providing directory support. That is being open and transparent.

Comment: This statement made me nervous: "Having a lot of data stored locally and not synced, which would be encouraged by unfettered directory access, will break this." From the related comments it was looking like not having a built-in sync would kill the feature. I felt some frustration, but now I am happy you went with the feature.